# Application exit issue in android

Tags: android, exit

I am trying to exit my application from my HOME button by calling `finish()` function. But, when I invoke `finish()`, the application is not exiting, but is going to close the previous activity. What should I do to resolve this? Thank you.

Comment: Read this question of SO --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon and this page: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/4c1b8955ebfd5799

Answer (score 0):

That's to be expected `finish()` only closes the current activity, but since all the activities launched are kept in an activity stack, the previously opened activity shows up. You can read more about this here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/activity_task_design.html#navigating_away_from_an_activity

Answer (score 0):

call moveTaskToBack(true) on your Activity (it doesn't kill your app but remove it from screen)

Answer (score 0):

when you want to close your application, you can call

```
  finishAffinity();
```

or if you want close it in background also you should write,

```
  android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

in AndroidManifest :

```
   <activity
    android:name="com.smart.remote.main.SplashActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
    android:excludeFromRecents="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

will move your application to background!